# Event triggered by Listbox and Radiobutton in Tkinter

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter, radio-button, eventhandler

I want to make an event that is triggered by either a change in List box selected item or a change in Radio button selected item. Is it possible? I use this code:

```
def getScript(event):
    state = rb.get()
    listScript = []
    processor = ()
    processor = lb1.get(lb1.curselection())
    if processor :
        if (state == 1):
            print processor
        if (state == 2):
            pass
        if (state == 3):
            pass


frame2 = Frame(top)
frame2.pack(fill = X)
rb = IntVar()

R1 = Radiobutton(frame2, text = "Parallel Test", 
                 variable = rb, value = 1, command = getScript)
R2 = Radiobutton(frame2, text = "Non Parallel Test", 
                 variable = rb, value = 2, command = getScript)
R3 = Radiobutton(frame2, text = "Specific Test", 
                 variable = rb, value = 3, command = getScript)

R1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10)
R2.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10)
R3.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 10)

frame3 = Frame(top)
frame3.pack(fill = X)
space_frame3 = Frame(frame3, width = 10)
l5 = Label(frame3, text = "Processor Unit")
l6 = Label(frame3, text = "Script for test")
lb1 = Listbox(frame3, height = 7, exportselection = 0)
lb1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',getScript)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame3)
lb2 = Listbox(frame3, height = 7, width = 40, 
              yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set, exportselection = 0)
```

Everything goes fine as long as I've selected a radiobutton before selecting an item in Listbox. But every time I select another radio button, it return:

```
TypeError: getScript() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happen when you select a Radiobutton is :

1) The intVar `rb` is set to the button value

2) The command getScript is called.

But, a Radiobutton selection do not generates any event, that's why there is 2 options in this case :

Call the function using a lambda function to provide a parameter as your command `getScript` expect one parameter ( that's the error message ).

```
R1 = Radiobutton(frame2, text = "Parallel Test",
                 variable = rb, value = 1,
                 command = lambda : getScript(None) )
```

An other option is - as it seem that your aim is to know what widget was selected - to use such a command:

```
R1 = Radiobutton(frame2, text = "Parallel Test",
                 variable = rb, value = 1,
                 command = lambda : getScript(R1) )
```

with your `getSript` function that takes a widget. Like this:

```
def getSript(widget):
    print widget["text"]
```

Comment: The first solution works fine for me. If I use the second solution, does it mean that I don't have to add 'event' argument to the getScript function? Does it change the binding of the listbox to the function? I'm just curious how it is possible to trigger the function from an event if I don't need to add the event to function argument. Thanks in advance

Comment: It is possible to call a function on event without providing the event if the function called do not depend of the event parameter such as the mouse position. For instance when passing `None` to your function you are saying that there is no event... So you are exactly calling a function on an event without needing it as a function argument ;) . My second proposition allow you to know what widgets was selected without global call to rb, that's all. You can imagine a function called without any argument that work using the rb value. You just have to remove the `event` parameter and it will work.