# Tkinter: Multiple Radio Buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I am creating a multiple choice test and a single question will have 3 parts (only 2 shown below - will add 3rd once I get this down).

I want the user to answer all parts, then hit submit button to record answers.

I have the prompts/choices in a class.

I display the choices and radio buttons, everything works generally. When all parts were not answered, it gives a warning. However my method for this is stupid. I currently display a message and then simply overwrite it with blanks when all choices are made and button clicked again. I cannot `.destroy` or `.remove` because if my conditions were not meant, son label was created and I get an error. I should probably put the display on a timer and then remove it maybe.

Ideally, my submit button would be disabled until all choices have been made instead, but I haven't figured that out yet either.

So can you either help me handle the warning message or disable the submit button until all radio button groups have a selection?

```
# First Group of Radio buttons
Radiobutton(manuframe, text=manu_questions.prompt1, padx=xpad, pady=ypad, bg=background,
            fg=text_color, font=(text_type, text_height), variable=man_answer,
            value=1).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(manuframe, text=manu_questions.prompt2, padx=xpad, pady=ypad, bg=background,
            fg=text_color, font=(text_type, text_height), variable=man_answer,
            value=2).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(manuframe, text=manu_questions.prompt3, padx=xpad, pady=ypad, bg=background,
            fg=text_color, font=(text_type, text_height), variable=man_answer,
            value=3).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(manuframe, text=manu_questions.prompt4, padx=xpad, pady=ypad, bg=background,
            fg=text_color, font=(text_type, text_height), variable=man_answer,
            value=4).pack(anchor=W)

#Second Group of Radio Buttons
Radiobutton(modelframe, text=model_questions.prompt1, padx=xpad, pady=ypad, bg=background,
            fg=text_color, font=(text_type, text_height), variable=mod_answer,
            value=1).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(modelframe, text=model_questions.prompt2, padx=xpad, pady=ypad, bg=background,
            fg=text_color, font=(text_type, text_height), variable=mod_answer,
            value=2).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(modelframe, text=model_questions.prompt3, padx=xpad, pady=ypad, bg=background,
            fg=text_color, font=(text_type, text_height), variable=mod_answer,
            value=3).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(modelframe, text=model_questions.prompt4, padx=xpad, pady=ypad, bg=background,
            fg=text_color, font=(text_type, text_height), variable=mod_answer,
            value=4).pack(anchor=W)

#Submit Button
submitButton = Button(btm_frame2, text="Submit", command=lambda:submit(q, question_count,
                      mod_answer, man_answer))
submitButton.pack()

#Submission function - Check all questions answered, if so increment question.
# index and continue.
def submit(q, question_count, mod_answer, man_answer):

    if mod_answer.get() == 0 or man_answer.get() == 0:
        warn_label =Label(btm_frame2, text="You didn't answer", bg="red", fg="white")
        warn_label.place(relx=.5, y=10, anchor=CENTER)
    else:
        replace_label = Label(btm_frame2,
                              text="                                            ",
                              bg="green", fg="white")
        replace_label.place(relx=.5, y=10, anchor=CENTER)
        if q == question_count:
            raise SystemExit(0)
        else:
            q = q + 1
```

Comment: I would suggest using one of the `tlinter.messagebox` dialogs to notify the user when they click submit they haven't answer all parts. Here's some [info](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524020423id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/tkMessageBox.html) on the kinds available. Also note that you should mention exactly what errors or warnings you're getting in your question.

Comment: @martineau you mean `tkinter.messagebox`?

Comment: Yes, I meant `tkinter.messagebox`. Anyway, if you [edit] your question and provide a runnable [mre], folks can show you how to implement what your want.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to solve this is by disabling the `'Submit'` button until both radio inputs (3 in the future, as you say) aren't filled.

By doing some research i found how to [Disable/Enable buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580507/disable-enable-button-in-tkinter) and also another post for [Radio button events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333769/event-triggered-by-listbox-and-radio-button-in-python-tkinter/26334386)

Basically you should have 3 boolean variables (for each group of radio buttons), have all of them set to `False`, and when you click to one of the buttons, you call a function that sets the variable to `True` (if it wasn't already), and checks if all the variables are already `True`, so the button can be enabled.

You may want to put these variables to `global`, so you can change the value.

Comment: So I basically did this. I set the variable I use in the Radiobutton to 0 and assign a value of 1 to 4 in the radio buttons set up. I then use the command:lambda and pass all three variables to a function that function that checks for nonzero values. If nonzero, the submit button is enabled.

Comment: Eric: While what you propose is certainly a viable and has certain advantages, a subtle downside to just disabling the Submit button until it can be pressed, is that there's no explicit indication of exactly _why_ it's in the state it's in. Human interface design can be a tricky subject…

Comment: Maybe in this case, a label could be added next to the button, to explain why it is disabled. The text of the label could be set to "" when the button is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based on your code — with enough scaffolding to actually be runnable — that illustrates how to simply display one of the built-in `tlinter.messagebox` [dialogs](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524020423id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/tkMessageBox.html) when all the choices weren't made.

An advantage of doing things this way is that it doesn't require destroying, removing, or blanking things out because that happens automatically when the user clicks the <kbd>OK</kbd> button acknowledging the message.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror


class Questions:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


manu_questions = Questions(
                    prompt1='manu prompt1',
                    prompt2='manu prompt2',
                    prompt3='manu prompt3',
                    prompt4='manu prompt4'
                 )

model_questions = Questions(
                    prompt1='model prompt1',
                    prompt2='model prompt2',
                    prompt3='model prompt3',
                    prompt4='model prompt4'
                  )

BACKGROUND = 'white'
TEXT_COLOR, TEXT_TYPE, TEXT_HEIGHT = 'black', 'arial.ttf', 12
XPAD, YPAD = 2, 2


root = Tk()

# First Group of Radio buttons
manuframe = Frame(root,  borderwidth=1, padx=4, pady=4)
manuframe.pack()
man_answer = IntVar(value=0)

Radiobutton(manuframe, text=manu_questions.prompt1, padx=XPAD, pady=YPAD, bg=BACKGROUND,
            fg=TEXT_COLOR, font=(TEXT_TYPE, TEXT_HEIGHT), variable=man_answer,
            value=1).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(manuframe, text=manu_questions.prompt2, padx=XPAD, pady=YPAD, bg=BACKGROUND,
            fg=TEXT_COLOR, font=(TEXT_TYPE, TEXT_HEIGHT), variable=man_answer,
            value=2).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(manuframe, text=manu_questions.prompt3, padx=XPAD, pady=YPAD, bg=BACKGROUND,
            fg=TEXT_COLOR, font=(TEXT_TYPE, TEXT_HEIGHT), variable=man_answer,
            value=3).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(manuframe, text=manu_questions.prompt4, padx=XPAD, pady=YPAD, bg=BACKGROUND,
            fg=TEXT_COLOR, font=(TEXT_TYPE, TEXT_HEIGHT), variable=man_answer,
            value=4).pack(anchor=W)

# Second Group of Radio Buttons
modelframe = Frame(root,  borderwidth=1, padx=4, pady=4)
modelframe.pack()
mod_answer = IntVar(value=0)

Radiobutton(modelframe, text=model_questions.prompt1, padx=XPAD, pady=YPAD, bg=BACKGROUND,
            fg=TEXT_COLOR, font=(TEXT_TYPE, TEXT_HEIGHT), variable=mod_answer,
            value=1).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(modelframe, text=model_questions.prompt2, padx=XPAD, pady=YPAD, bg=BACKGROUND,
            fg=TEXT_COLOR, font=(TEXT_TYPE, TEXT_HEIGHT), variable=mod_answer,
            value=2).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(modelframe, text=model_questions.prompt3, padx=XPAD, pady=YPAD, bg=BACKGROUND,
            fg=TEXT_COLOR, font=(TEXT_TYPE, TEXT_HEIGHT), variable=mod_answer,
            value=3).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(modelframe, text=model_questions.prompt4, padx=XPAD, pady=YPAD, bg=BACKGROUND,
            fg=TEXT_COLOR, font=(TEXT_TYPE, TEXT_HEIGHT), variable=mod_answer,
            value=4).pack(anchor=W)


# Submit Button
submitButton = Button(root, text="Submit",
                      command=lambda: submit(man_answer, mod_answer))
submitButton.pack()

def submit(*variables):
    """ Check all questions answered. """
    question_not_answered = any(not v.get() for v in variables)
    if question_not_answered:
        showerror('Screw Up!', f"Answer all {len(variables)} parts before submission")
    else:
        ... # Whatever you want to happen when they are all answered.


root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot showing error dialog being displayed after clicking the button:

[image: Screenshot showing error message]

---

For quick reference, here's a sample of what all the other `tkinter.messagebox` dialogs look like:

[image: sample of dialogs available]

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't know if I like the warning box or not though. But it definitely is a viable solution so thank you.